# JWT token for logged in user Passport OpenIdConnect

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, openid-connect

I'm migrating the passport library version on my node project from 0.4.0 to 0.6.0, and while migrating I noticed that the accessToken is not part of the user object anymore on the newer versions of passport, so for example, while on 0.4.0 i was able to do something like this:

```js
router.get('/', authChecker.forFrontEnd, (req, res) => {
  const {exp} = jwt_decode(req.user.accessToken);
  res.render('index', {
    //...
  })
});
```

Now the accessToken is undefined when retrieveing it from `req.user.accessToken`.

Did it get moved into another place on newer versions?

The passport library is being used in my React project that has an express middleware with passport handling the authentication part and I need to send the accessToken to the React client

PS: I do have the correct enocde/decode user functions setup for passport, as a matter of fact the user object is still there, just not with the accessToken anymore:

```
user: {
    id: 'soemrandomid',
    displayName: 'xxxxx xxxxxx',
    username: 'xxx@xxxxxx.com',
    emails: [ [Object] ]
}
```

Also I have the session setup the following way:

```js
app.use(session({
  secret: vault.get('SESSION_SECRET'),
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false
}));
app.use(passportPolyfill);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Where passportPolifyll is a workaround to the bug with cookie session on the 0.6.0 version of it:

```
const passportPolyfill = ( req, _res, next ) => {

  if (req.session && !req.session.regenerate) {
    req.session.regenerate = (cb) => {
      cb();
    };
  }
  if (req.session && !req.session.save) {
    req.session.save = (cb) => {
      cb();
    };
  }
  next();
};
```